# Is there a way for .net core to load js/css asynchronous?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

My project has a google font css to load,such as:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa|Julius+Sans+One+Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
```

However,maybe my network is not well or any other problem,I tried and found it wasting a long time to load.

So I wonder to load it asynchronous.

I knowed there is some JavaScript and stylesheet loader,such as RequireJS can do it.

But I wanna that if I can do it without js but using .net core?

I tried using:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync()
```

to load a cshtml which contains the stylesheet to solve it,but it seems no use.

Would you please tell me if it is a way for .net core to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will load it asynchronously or to be more specific in parallel **if** the `<link/>` and `<script />` elements are defined in the HTML header.

This has **nothing to do with ASP.NET Core**. It's how browsers work. However there are limits. The browser usually limits the number of connections which can be done to a single domain. Typically that's around 6 to 8 connection per domain.

So if you get gazillions of scripts from the same domain it may take longer than if they are distributed among other networks.

Using CDNs can be helpful as if a user once visits a website which contains a specific script, css or font it will be downloaded there and held in cache. If a user visits another website which uses the exactly same resources, they will be just uses from cache again even if the websites belong to different persons or companies. Popular examples are popular versions of jQuery libraries loaded via CDN.

Please keep in mind, `<link />` and `<script />` directives which are **NOT** inside the HTML `<header>` sections, won't be loaded in parallel but in sequence.

In ASP.NET Core you can use the

```
@scripts
{
    <link ... />
}
```

section to include scripts in a specific section (in Razor templates it will be inserted in the section where `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` is located), **IF** you need to do that conditionally (i.e. only add specific link or script tags on a specific view, otherwise use `_Layout.cshtml' -- iirc)

```
@await Html.PartialAsync()
```

has nothing to do with it. Its for server-sided processing, the browser never knows anything about it. Its used to improve performance and throughput (how many requests it can handle under heavy load) of your server, when you do I/O operations in your partials (reading database, writing files or sending/receiving something over the network).

#### Edit

When developing locally, you may want to avoid accessing CDN if you know you may or may not have an internet connection while developing and testing. In this case you may want to use the `<environment>` variables to switch based on your environment

```
<environment names="Development">
    <!-- add your local dependencies here pointing the location of your lib folder where npm packages are located such as ~/lib/jQuery/... -->
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <!-- Add your CDN links in here. Configure a fallback if connection doesnt work see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.linktaghelper?view=aspnetcore-2.0 -->
</environment>
```

Comment: Thank you for explain so clearly.I think my mistake is puting the stylesheet not in head.I trid put it into <head> and it seems works.

Comment: My project should support IE also.I wonder if IE can load stylesheet parallel in <head>?

Comment: Don't have any source on top of my head, but every recent browser (released in the past 5 to 8 years) should be able to support it